# How to stub cross-fetch with sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sinon

In my node project I'm using Sinon and I'm having issues with mocking cross-fetch lib.

So basically I have a simple service which is calling cross-fetch internally something more or less like this:

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

public async sendMyData(id): Promise<void> {
      const payload = await this.generatePayload(id);
      await sendRequest(payload, id);
  }
```

And then fetch is called like this:

```
private async sendRequest(payload, id): Promise<void> {
      await fetch(`http://my-api-url/endpoint/${id}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(payload)
      });
  }
```

So in my tests I want to create my service and mock cross-fetch and inspect with what payload it has been called.

Comment: Which method do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test sendMyData which is calling sendRequest and this one uses fetch internally. I know that I could use jest to mock the whole module but unfortunately we can't use jest in our project.

Comment: You can use http mock library like: [fetch-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-mock) or [nock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock). Or are you have to use sinon only?

Comment: The issue is that I have to use sinon. But I think there’s also http mock in the project. How one could mock internal http call in a private method with that?